# Azure Ad fails to update users using Patch on microsoft.systemForCrossDomainIdentityManagement nuget package

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, scim2

We have created a SCIM integration using 
`microsoft.systemForCrossDomainIdentityManagement` nuget package which has been described in here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups

We have tested the APIs using Postman and they work as they should but when we test them with Azure AD the patch requests fail.

Looking at the logs and narrowing them down we figured that the request is not in the same format as what microsoft.systemForCrossDomainIdentityManagement expects.

One patch request from AD is like below (which will fail):

> { "schemas":["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"],
>   "Operations": [ {"op":"Replace","path":"displayName","value":" User
>   X"} ]}

While the request that works is like this:

> {"schemas":["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"]
>   ,
>
> "Operations":[
>   {"op":"Replace","path":"displayName","value":
>
> [ {"$ref":null,"value":"User x"}]}]
>
> }}

- Please note the difference between 2 requests which in the 1st call is a string and in the second one is a list of objects.

How should we fix this?

The Nuget package take the request and deliver the IPatchRequest so the request doesn't even receive to our part of the code and both parts are Microsoft :|

Comment: Hi Ashkan, I see you made a Github issue for this as well. Do you receive an error message or does it just not update?

Comment: @MarileeTurscak-MSFT Hi and thanks for the reply. Yes, I get: Failed to update User 'xxx@yyy.zzz' in customappsso; Error: StatusCode: BadRequest Message: Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details. Web Response: {"Message":"The request is invalid."}. We will retry this operation on the next synchronization attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no answer from Microsoft after more than a month, they only other way that I know to fix this is to intercept the call before it gets to Microsoft's part of the code (using a middle ware) and change it to the format that they are expecting :\

I have discussed the problem and the solution further in the link below, but I am still waiting for a fix from Microsoft :\
http://pilpag.blogspot.com/2019/02/enabling-scim-using-microsoftsystemforc.html

The easy fix is like this:

```
public class PatchRequestUpdaterMiddleware : OwinMiddleware

{

     private const string OperationValueFinderRegex = "({[\\s\\w\":,.\\[\\]\\\\]*op[\\s\\w\":,.\\[\\]\\\\]*\"value\"\\s*:\\s*)(\"[\\w\\s\\-,.@?!*;\'\\(\\)]+\")"; //{"op":"x","value":"Andrew1"}

public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)

    {

        if (context.Request.Method.ToLower() != "patch")

        {

            await Next.Invoke(context);

            return;

        }

        var streamReader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body);

        string body = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        body = Regex.Replace(body, OperationValueFinderRegex, m => $"{m.Groups[1].Value}[{{\"value\":{m.Groups[2].Value}}}]"); //{"op":"x","value":"Ashkan"} ==>> {"op":"x","value":[{"value":"Ashkan"}]}

        context.Request.Body = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body));

        await Next.Invoke(context);

    }

 }
```

And just add this to the provider that you have created:

```
class myProvider:ProviderBase

{

....

   private void OnServiceStartup(IAppBuilder appBuilder, HttpConfiguration configuration)

        {

...

  appBuilder.Use<PatchRequestUpdaterMiddleware>();

...

}
```